# How to convert these mapping coordinates

Tags: coordinates, mapping

I have an older database at work and I've been asked to map the
recorded GPS coordinates for each record.  Unfortunately, I can't
figure out the map coordinates that were recorded.

As an example, 1301 Calle Oriente in Milpitas California shows as:

06158991  and 01987998

If I look at google maps, 1301 Calle Oriente is 37.446687, -121.886884

Is there a website that I convert 06158991 and 01987998 to a map like
google maps?  Is this a valid mapping coordinate format?  If so,
please let me know what format this is.

Answer (score 6):

With `EPSG:2227 NAD83 / California zone 3 (ft US)` The result looks quiet good:

[image]

EPSG:2872 and 3494 have the same proj definition.

You can load the data as delimited text layer into QGIS, assign projection EPSG:2227 to it, and `Rightclick -> Save As ...` to WGS84 (EPSG:4326) under a different name. Just take care that usually x is positive East, and y is North.

Comment: +1 and Another word of caution to @user16258 : please do that to several points, and check whether there are similar biases/offsets; you may want to find another projection that has lower error (in the mean square sense).

Comment: +1 as well.  @DeerHunter - It is always good to check for a different projection that might work better.  In this case, however, I doubt if he would find one.  Those coordinates that he listed directly match the coordinate ranges in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Plane_Coordinate_System which is represented by EPSG 2227 for Zone 3 in California.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Is there a website that I can easily enter any coordinate that I have in this database and convert it to something that I can display at maps.google.com?

Comment: You could try http://twcc.free.fr/#, but they don't have feet CRS, only metres. You can add custom CRS with the definitions from spatialreference.org. Another site is http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/ It knows `EPSG:2872`. I would suggest using QGIS. It can import a whole excel or CSV table at once.